# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, when logging asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do system log and I keep getting this error. The logger object is Clearly instialized.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
**Source File:** C:\Users\Victor\DEV\chams\repos-development\confirm-me-api-1\Utility\AuditLogAttribute.cs.    **Line**: 65

```cs
using ConfirmMeAPI.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ActionFilterAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute;

namespace ConfirmMeAPI.Utility
{
    public class AuditLogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        cfmWS.WebService _cfm = new cfmWS.WebService();
        GeolocationResponse _geolocation = new GeolocationResponse();
        Logger _logger = new Logger();
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        string baseurl;
        public AuditLogAttribute()
        {
            baseurl = "http://ip-api.com";
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /* THE ERROR LINE */ _logger.LogError(ex.ToString() + ex.InnerException.ToString() + ex.StackTrace.ToString());

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely `.InnerException` that will be null. Not all exceptions have one.

You should only need to log `ex.ToString()` and the `InnerException` and `StackTrace` will be logged as part of that anyway.

And depending on which logger it is, you may be OK just logged `ex` and it will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Object reference related errors are run time errors, which normally comes when you try to refer a variables or any data items returning value null. Make sure you have initialized that variable of data items.